# Because we can pass the $\limsup$ on both sides: conceptual doubt.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}<2\epsilon<\frac{1}{3^n}$. If I know that
\begin{equation}
\frac{-\log(N(X,\epsilon))}{\log(\epsilon)}\leq \frac{\log(2^{n+1})}{\log(2\cdot 3^n)}\Rightarrow \limsup_{\epsilon'\to 0} \frac{-\log(N(X,\epsilon'))}{\log(\epsilon')}\leq \limsup_{m\to +\infty}\frac{\log(2^{m+1})}{\log(2\cdot 3^m)}
\end{equation}

So why can we "pass" the $\limsup$ on both sides of this inequality, if on the right side we would have the $\limsup$ of functions and on the left side a $\limsup$ of sequences. That is, we would have different $\limsup$.

Does anyone know how to explain why we can do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your first inequality must include some relationship between $\epsilon$ and $n$. 

I would also note that we can calculate $$\underset{m\to+\infty}{\lim\sup} \frac{\log(2^{m+1})}{\log(2\cdot 3^m)} = \log(2)/\log(3).$$ This is actually a limit, not just lim sup.

Comment: yes, $\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}<2\epsilon<\frac{1}{3^n}$, but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question when you don't include all relevant details.

Comment: You should edit the question to include all relevant details. Not just put the details in the comments.

Comment: Okay, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have some function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, some sequence $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, and a function $\phi:(0,1)\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $$f(\varepsilon) \leqslant g_{\phi(\varepsilon)}$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Assume also that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\phi(\varepsilon)=\infty$.

Then $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon)\leqslant \underset{m}{\lim\sup} g_m.$$ This includes the problem, as you've specified it, where we choose $\phi(\varepsilon)$ to be the minimum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/3^{n+1}<2\varepsilon\leqslant 1/3^n$.

Recall that $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon)=\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim}\underset{\delta\in (0,\varepsilon)}{\sup} f(\delta).$$ Recall also that $$\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m = \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim}\underset{n\geqslant m}{\sup} g_n.$$

We work by contradiction. Assume that $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon) > \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m.$$  Fix $B$ such that $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon) > B > \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m.$$  Since $B>\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m$, there exists some $m_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_{m\geqslant m_0} g_m\leqslant B$.   Since $\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim}\phi(\varepsilon)=\infty$, there exists $\varepsilon_0\in (0,1)$ such that $\phi(\varepsilon)\geqslant m_0$ for all $\varepsilon\in (0,\varepsilon_0)$.   Since $\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon)>B$, there exists $\varepsilon\in (0,\varepsilon_0)$ such that $f(\varepsilon)>B$. However, since $\phi(\varepsilon)\geqslant m_0$, we have $$B<f(\varepsilon) \leqslant g_{\phi(\varepsilon)}\leqslant B,$$ a contradiction.

A faster way to get at this which omits some of the details would be: Assume that $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon) > \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m.$$  Fix $B$ such that $$\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon) > B > \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} g_m.$$  Since $\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim\sup} f(\varepsilon) > B$, we can fix a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon_n=0$ and $\inf_n f(\varepsilon_n)\geqslant B$. Since $\underset{\varepsilon\to 0^+}{\lim}\phi(\varepsilon)=\infty$, we can pass to a subsequence and assume that $(\phi(\varepsilon_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is strictly increasing. Then $(g_{\phi(\varepsilon_n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a subsequence of $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, so $$B\leqslant \inf_n f(\varepsilon_n) \leqslant \inf_n g_{\phi(\varepsilon_n)} \leqslant \lim\sup_n g_{\varphi(\varepsilon_n)} \leqslant \lim\sup_n g_n<B,$$ a contradiction.